# how can i compare date strings?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

i need to check whether the **date** is between **minDate** and **maxDate**.
 but when i try to compare with minDate, i should get valid as false but am getting true..

```js
            let minDate = "27-05-2019";
        let maxDate = "27-05-2019";
        let date = "13-02-2018";
        var valid;

        if(new Date(date.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")).toDateString() >= new Date(minDate.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")).toDateString()){
            valid = true;
            } else {
            valid = false;
            }
            
            console.log(valid);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the Date object from JavaScript: https://wiki.base22.com/btg/how-to-compare-dates-in-javascript-81791002.html

Comment: You're comparing the string representation of the dates. Compare the dates directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain JS solution with a couple of helper functions:

```
const splitMyDateString = str => {
  const [day, mon, yr] = str.split('-').map(Number);
  return [yr, mon, day];
};

const makeDate = ([yr, mon, day]) => {
  return new Date(yr, mon - 1, day);
};

let minDate = makeDate(splitMyDateString("27-05-2019"));
let maxDate = makeDate(splitMyDateString("27-05-2019"));
let date = makeDate(splitMyDateString("13-02-2018"));
let valid = (date >= minDate) && (date <= maxDate);
```

Note that the Date constructor is not guaranteed to accept strings except in the ISO 8601 format. So here we're passing [integers instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax). Note also we have to subtract 1 from the month because JS months are 0-11, not 1-12.

Answer (score 2):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

isBetween - [link](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

```
moment().isBetween(moment-like, moment-like);
```

**Example**

```
let minDate = "27-05-2019";
let maxDate = "27-05-2019";
let date = "13-02-2018";

moment(date).isBetween(moment(minDate), moment(maxDate));
```

Comment: i just need to compare with plain javascript

Comment: @NandhaKumar while I have some sympathy (moment is a *massive* increase in payload just to compare a couple of dates) that's the sort of thing that should be a stated requirement in the question itself.

Comment: @LukeWalker your plain JS answer is wrong, or at best incomplete: he Date object constructor is only (per the spec) guaranteed to work with integer arguments or Date strings in ISO 8601 format, which yours are not.

Comment: thanks @luke. please up vote this question if u really feel it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `toDateString()` method, you are converting your `Date` object to a string, thus you are only comparing two strings in your `if`.

Remove this method call and it should work.

```js
let minDate = "27-05-2019";
let maxDate = "27-05-2019";
let date = "13-02-2018";
var valid;

if (new Date(date.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")) >= new Date(minDate.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"))) {
  valid = true;
} else {
  valid = false;
}

console.log(valid);
```

Comment: @JaredSmith, you are right :), just kept using the date as it was being used, but probably it would be better to split the date into integers before converting into `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript Date method: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

```js
let minDate = new Date("2018-01-13"),
    maxDate = new Date("2018-03-13"),
    date = new Date("2018-02-13"),
    valid = false;

if (date.getTime() >= minDate.getTime() && date.getTime() <= maxDate.getTime()) {
    valid = true;
}
```